How to set accessibility identifier for navigation back button?
I tried to add an identifier for the navigation back item, but is not working anymore. Before I've added the the accessibilityLabel, it was working, but I also need this one too. The label is working, but the identifier is not anymore. What can be the issue ?
navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem?.accessibilityLabel = AccessibiltyIds.backA11y.localized

I tried the following
navigationBar.backItem?.backBarButtonItem?.accessibilityIdentifier = AccessibiltyIds.back
navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem?.accessibilityIdentifier = AccessibiltyIds.back

    private struct AccessibiltyIds {
        static let back = "back"
        static let backA11y = "backarrow"
    }

